# how to ignore SSL certificate is signed by an unknown certificate authority problem?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, powershell

I'm developing c# application to call Exchange Management Shell Cmdlets. It always comes out with an exception of "The server certificate on the destination computer (208.243.XX.2XX:443) has the following errors:
The SSL certificate is signed by an unknown certificate authority.
The SSL certificate contains a common name (CN) that does not match the hostname. "

But I did write code to accept all certificate, don't know why still get the error.

My code:

```
    PSCredential credential = new PSCredential("administrator", securePwd);

    WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://208.243.49.20/powershell"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", credential);
    connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;

    Runspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
    PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
    PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
    command.AddCommand("New-Mailbox");
    command.AddParameter("Name", "TestName");
    powershell.Commands = command;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
    delegate { return true; }
);
    try
    {
        runspace.Open();//This is where the exception happens
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;
        Collection<PSObject> result= powershell.Invoke();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WSManConnectionInfo` object has two properties to skip certificate checks.

```
connectionInfo.SkipCACheck = true;

connectionInfo.SkipCNCheck = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Brent, try putting the ServicePointManager call as the first call you make, before even creating the Uri.

The delegate is also missing some parameters, however. Give this a shot:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for replying. I put your code on the first line, still got the same error. Maybe it has nothing to do with ServerCertificateValidationCallback?

Comment: Beautiful! And it's shorter than the previous solutions I used, and does not require additional namespace imports.

Answer (score 3):

I think Brent is correct re: needs to be in the PowerShell process. You'll need a line like the following in your PS:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback += { $true }
```

Did the following test against an untrusted SSL site and confirmed it overrides the error:

```
$url = "https://www.us.army.mil"
$wc = new-object system.net.webclient
$x = $wc.downloadstring($url) # will fail
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback += { $true }
$x = $wc.downloadstring($url) # should succeed
```

... That said, it's strange that you say the exception happens upon opening the runspace, if that's the case then maybe not, since you aren't even getting to the point of execution of the PowerShell code.

Comment: That's great! I tested your script in PS, it just like you said, I need it run in PS. But I don't know how to add that line in PowerShell process. I wrote command.AddScript("[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback+={$true}"); but it doesn't work. How to add this script in PS?

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark: perhaps set the ServicePointManager delegate before you create the instance of runspace.  I'm just speculating that construction of the runspace instance might capture and store the delegate from ServicePointManager.

Also, be sure the question answered by the delegate is what you think.  Is it asking "valid certificat?" or is it asking "invalid certificate?"  If the latter, then change your delegate to { return false; }

**One last thing: is powershell executing from a seperate process?  If yes, then the ServicePointManager setting won't help you.**

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I moved ServicePointManager before creating the instance of runspace, same error. I changed return true to return false, same error. I'm not sure if powershell executing from a seperate process, but it seems that ServicePointManager  has nothing to do in this process. If it is a seperate process, what should do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am becoming quite convinced this is because powershell is running in a separate process.  You need to have the powershell script do the equivalent of the ServicePointManager configuration step.